# Remove elements from array by type of element

Tags: javascript, arrays, testcomplete

I have an array and I want to remove all the string elements from it.
This is what I have so far. The result is not what I want since it returns only "bicycle"

Also, I am doing this in Test Complete so I need to have a main function that logs the result.

```
function ex06(){


  var mailBox = "mailbox";
  var twenty = 20;
  var isItRaining = true;
  var goat = "";
  var stringsArray = ["bicycle", "pocket", 3, mailBox, twenty, isItRaining, goat];

  var result = removeStrings();
  Log.Message("stringsArray looks like this after the removal of all the string elements: " + result);

  function removeStrings(){

    var i;
    var x
    for(i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++){
      if (typeof(stringsArray[i]) === 'string'){
        x = stringsArray.splice(i, 1);
        return x;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"The result is not what I want since it returns only "bicycle""* What is it *supposed* to return? Since it modifies the original array. Is it supposed to return the strings it removes?

Comment: I want to return an array containing the elements that are not string

Comment: Then see option 2 in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Version 1, with Array#filter

```js
var a = [1, 2, "3", "4", true];

a = a.filter(function (e) {
    return typeof e !== 'string';
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Version 2, with Array#splice and running backwards.

```js
var a = [1, 2, "3", "4", true],
    i = a.length;

while (i--) {
    if (typeof a[i] === 'string') {
        a.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is what you need:

```
var stringsArray = ["bicycle", "pocket", 3, mailBox, twenty, isItRaining, goat];
var result = stringsArray.filter(function(element) {
   return typeof element !== 'string';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to reduce the `counter` variable and check the original array

try this simple example

```
var a = [1,2,"3", "4", true];
for( var counter = 0; counter < a.length; counter++)
{
   if ( (typeof a[ counter ] ) == "string" ) 
   { 
     a.splice(counter,1); counter--; 
   }
}

console.log(a); //output [1, 2, true]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an exercise, and that's why you're not using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The problem is that you have your `return x` *inside* your `for` loop, so you return the first string you find.

You have at least three options:

1. Don't return anything, since `removeStrings` is modifying the original array. That one's easy: Just remove the `return x;` line.
2. Don't modify the original array; instead, create and return a new array with the strings left out. In that case, you'd start with `x = []` before the loop, remove the `splice` call, and instead push any non-string onto `x`.
3. Modify the original array, and create and return a new array containing the strings you've removed. In that case, you'd remove `return x` from inside the loop, have `x = []` before the loop, and push the entries you remove onto `x`. Then `return x` at the end.

In any of the places where you're modifying the original, note [gurvinder372's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572363/157247) that when you remove an entry, you need to not increase the index counter, as you'll end up skipping the next entry.

I wouldn't do it the way he suggests, though; when I'm looping through an array modifying it, `for` isn't what I reach for, I reach for `while`:

```
i = 0;
while (i < stringsArray.length) {
    if (typeof stringsArray[i] === 'string'){
        stringsArray.splice(i, 1);
        // We leave `i` alone here, because we need to process
        // the new `stringsArray[i]` on the next pass
    } else {
        // Didn't remove this entry, move past it
        ++i;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: `typeof` isn't a function, it's an operator, there's no need to put its operand in `()`:
`if (typeof stringsArray[i] === 'string'){`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
function ex06(){


  var mailBox = "mailbox";
  var twenty = 20;
  var isItRaining = true;
  var goat = "";
  var stringsArray = ["bicycle", "pocket", 3, mailBox, twenty, isItRaining, goat];

  var result = removeStrings();

  Log.Message("stringsArray looks like this after the removal of all the string elements: " + result);

  function removeStrings(){
     var newarray = [];
    var i;
    var x
    for(i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++){
      if (typeof(stringsArray[i]) !== 'string'){
        newarray.push(stringsArray[i]);

      } 
    }
   return newarray
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript offers native methods to filter arrays, so that you can remove string elements more easily: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can make the process a lot easier (and prevents strange behaviours when using splice inside a loop).

```
function ex06(){


  var mailBox = "mailbox";
  var twenty = 20;
  var isItRaining = true;
  var goat = "";
  var stringsArray = ["bicycle", "pocket", 3, mailBox, twenty, isItRaining, goat];

  var result = removeStrings(stringsArray);
  Log.Message("stringsArray looks like this after the removal of all the string elements: " + result);

  function removeStrings(arrayWithString){

    return arrayWithString.filter(function(item) {
      return typeof item !== 'string'; // returns only items which are not strings
    });
  }
}
```

A small piece of advice: Pass in the array into your function instead of referencing it from the parent scope. This way you have a pure, reusable function (and no strange side effects you might not want).